# played - диапазон который был проигран

Tags: javascript, видео

Предположим пользователь просмотрел видео, местами.

```
video.played
```

played - покажет количество, через цикл возможно разобрать

Вопрос в том, предположим пользователь ранее просматривал видео. Возможно ли ранее отрезки которые были просмотрены, добавить их перед повторным просмотром видео?

Comment: Записывать все отрезки в LocalStorage и вытаскивать их для отображения... Ну, если, судя по Вашей логике, новые куски всё же можно получить во время текущего просмотра

Comment: Здорового... Вопрос был в том, возможно ли изначально добавить отрезки перед повторным просмотром. Чтобы логика перестроила их с учетом новых просмотров, а затем взять их и обновить в бд данные по ним...